# openid connect in identityserver4

Tags: identityserver4

Following along the identityServer4 tutorial [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html) and [here](https://github.com/rm2k/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/dev/Quickstarts/3_ImplicitFlowAuthentication/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Config.cs#L70.), I see `RedirectUris` being set to `/signin-oidc`. I tried searching what's happening at that endpoint or rather the location of it's implementation, but with no success.

```
new Client
{
  ...
  // where to redirect to after login
  RedirectUris = { "http://localhost:5002/signin-oidc" }
}
```

Where can I find the implementations of `/signin-oidc` and `/signout-oidc` in these IdentifyServer tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

That is the [default](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/OpenIdConnectOptions.cs#L51) callback path of the `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` middleware. You can check out the repository to see how it works but basically it just populates the User principle for authorization.